# Is describing something as 'detailed and concise' an oxymoron?

Tags: adjectives, oxymoron

For example:

> The instructions must be detailed and concise.

Comment: Are *detailed* and *concise* contrary notions? No. Have you checked?

Comment: It helps to think in terms of information density.  Lots of information (detailed) in a small space (concise).

Comment: There's a contrast, so I'd use 'detailed yet concise'. // The default meaning of 'oxymoron' is 'a concisely stated paradox' rather than 'a concisely stated contradiction in terms'.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, "detailed and concise" is not an oxymoron.  Not any more than describing a crust as [tender and flaky](http://www.bakeorbreak.com/2007/11/alton-browns-pie-crust/) would be.  Both are statements of balanced purposes, which together shape the desired result.

*[Detailed](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/detailed)* in context means "thoroughly describing all relevant parts."

*[Concise](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concise)* in context means "free of superfluous detail."

Hence, "detailed and concise" means "thoroughly describing all relevant parts without superfluous detail."

Comment: _why_ must you describe a [delicious pie](http://www.recipe.com/images/triple-delicious-pie-R049557-ss.jpg). Berries aren't even in season in North America..

Answer (score 5):

I think it is not an oxymoron; the phrase "detailed and concise" enforces an idea. In this case an oxymoron might be "detailed summary".

Comment: Something can be a detailed summary if the original version was yet more detailed (from 1000000 words to 10000 words). But that's nit-picking.

Answer (score 4):

*Compendious* is a single word meaning "detailed and concise". If the latter is an oxymoron, then the former would be a single-word example of an oxymoron.

Answer (score 3):

At first reading it does seem to be, but it could be taken to mean 'as concise as possible while covering all the details'.

Comment: You are right. Substantiate your answer and it may get qualified as *the* answer even. Include more supporting information citing reliable sources.

Comment: In resumes, we use 'brief and descriptive', which is accepted as usual; not an oxymoron.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are partially right.

*Detailed* is sometimes used as a euphemism for "long-winded".  As in,

> Those instructions are rather, uh, *detailed*.

So if the word *detailed* is not intended as a euphemism, then it is in the very least a wrong word choice.  What he probably meant to say was *exact* instead.  As in

> The instructions must be *exact* and *concise*.